# Why do we have androidMain in shared module in addition to the Android project's build.gradle.kts?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

In KMM we have a `build.gradle.kts` for the shared module which includes amongst others:

```
sourceSets {
    val commonMain by getting {
        dependencies {
            //put your multiplatform dependencies here
            // ...
        }
    }
    val androidMain by getting { // note androidMain here
        dependencies {
            // some stuff like sqldelight android driver goes here
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

In addition we also have a `build.gradle.kts` in the `androidApp` folder.

So, when would one put dependencies in the `androidMain` section of the shared module `build.gradle.kts` and when would one put it in the  `build.gradle.kts` in the `androidApp` folder? Why do we have an `androidMain` section at all in the `build.gradle.kts` of the shared module if the shared module is supposed to be platform independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do we have an androidMain section at all in the build.gradle.kts of the shared module if the shared module is supposed to be platform independent?

The shared module is not platform-independent. The source sets can be, for example `commonMain`. However, you can have `androidMain`, `iosMain`, etc. Those source sets are platform-specific.

If you are using `expect/actual`, the compiler will look to satisfy all `expect` declarations. So, say you have:

```kotlin
expect fun hello():String
```

If you define Android and iOS as targets, you'll need an `actual` for each, in the shared Kotlin module.

In `androidMain`:

```kotlin
actual fun hello() = "Hi from Android"
```

In `iosMain`:

```kotlin
actual fun hello() = "Hi from iOS"
```

If the compiler can't find a matching `actual` for each target to satisfy the `expect`, the build will fail. You can't put those `actual` declarations in the `androidApp`. They need to be satisfied directly in the shared module.

Comment: ah, your last sentence was the most important one for me. That's what I didn't know until now. Thank you for your reply :-)